# Fonts: what, when and how to use them?

Tags: html

A question to experiences web developers here:

As far web page design goes how to maximize the effectiveness of font choice so that it's non-intrusive yet as effective as possible to the end user ? From your experience. An example I like a lot and I would like to model pages with such fluent choice of fonts as this page: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/)

Thanks for sharing your know-hows!
J.

Comment: @Pekka: I mean how to combine fonts in a way that you combine similar/matching colours to make up a web page's color scheme. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe more suitable on `graphicdesign.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: @Pekka: I am not sure, I suppose it may be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading the following articles:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/04/best-practices-of-combining-typefaces/
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/01/css-and-the-future-of-text/